# Uninstalling JAMBOX by Jawbone

Tags: bluetooth, system-settings, macos

I've uninstalled the Jawbone Updater software by deleting it from `/Applications`. However, I'm still seeing the JAMBOX by Jawbone as a Bluetooth output and input in the System Preferences panel.

[image]

I tried to delete these using the command:

```
$ sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/jawbone.kext
```

But received the error message:

```
(kernel) Kext com.aliph.driver.jstub not found for unload request.
Failed to unload com.aliph.driver.jstub - (libkern/kext) not found.
```

How can I delete these Bluetooth inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the JAMBOX from the Bluetooth Prefs Pane in System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: No. I hadn't. Deleting the JAMBOX from the Bluetooth system preferences pane also removed JAMBOX from the Sound preferences pane. Thanks.